# Realtime Search with AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

What is the best way to push data to a client in real time? I am working on a test website with the new html5 history API when I ran into this conundrum.

I am using the twitter API to make real time search for learning purposes, but

So I understand that you could essentially submit a form over and over again, spamming PHP endlessly, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

What is the best way to get data as data is created? (with jQuery, preferably)

Thanks, David

Edit: I've looked into push engines, but there's *got* to be a way to do it without buying a service, right?

Comment: For push technology, you don't have to buy anything if you already own a server?

Comment: I'm not sure what the current state of things are but in order for a server to push a connection needs to stay open. Is this something you'd want from a web server? Especially if the connection isn't doing anything for long periods of time. Some clients might support websocket, not sure about server-sent events. It used to be done with a technique called comet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29 My guess is that the server and client sends the right headers (connection: keep-alive) with a high timeout.

Comment: Just doing this for educational purposes, I don't think I would want to get a server for push. I think I'll look into web sockets and polling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (actually more than that if you include browser plugins like flash) possible solutions I see: websockets and polling.  You don't like the idea of polling, and I would agree, depending on the scenario.  Polling has the drawback of keeping a user's session alive - i.e. they'll never get logged out - if it's polling the same domain.  However if you set it to poll every 5 seconds, the load is very minimal assuming you set it up to check for new data.  With jQuery you could implement a setInterval to poll (as I'm sure you've already investigated).  On another note... WCF introduces an HTTP-based TCP-socket-like connection called polling duplex that allows both client and server to communicate as if they were connected via TCP.  You can look up the performance on these - it's not that bad if you wanted to implement that somehow. I used Silverlight to implement this. Websockets are a relatively new technology that gives you two-way communication, but you're limiting your clients to those that use browsers that support these.  You also have to deal with browser-specifics.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I'll look into web sockets and polling and work with those on my learning adventures (I am a strong believer in not using plugins such as flash and silverlight for websites). Because I'll be using an API to get my information, however, it seems like the 5 second polling may be the best option. I'm on my phone right now; will look into websockets later. Once again, thanks :)

Comment: Just tried out websockets with php. Was not reliable. I guess I'll stick with polling.